# Why does hovering in the Chrome debugger actually modify variables rather than evaluating an expression?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, type-conversion, google-chrome-devtools

so I have this code:

```
var a = 3;
debugger;
console.log(a += a > 2)
```

now for whatever reason (some type coercion is happening that i'm not really familiar with in this case) the boolean expression combined with the incremental operator increases **a** by 1.

however, when I hover the the **(a += a>3)** in the chrome debugger, it will actually run the operation. so if I hover over that part 5 times, it will actually run that operation 5 times. Instead of the normal runtime giving an output of 4, i will get 8 just because i hovered over it five times.

Why doesn't it only run the operation once and check the value as a result of that singular operation? If I hover a block of code 1000 times shouldn't it only output the result of that block of code as if it was only run once?

Comment: I can't make the latest version of Chrome run the expressions on mouseover. Regarding why `a` increases: It seems like `true` converted to a number equals `1` i.e. `+true === 1`. So what you're getting is `a += 1`

Comment: Mouseover should be highlight. Highlighting an area will execute the operations within it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is now, you have paused the VM running against that code. You paused time and are looking at the state as it is. By highlighting the operation you are executing that code within that state to see how it will evaluate. Which then, because that is what this code does, a becomes the outcome of that execution within the VM. This is done as many times as you cause execution to occur again. Then upon stepping forward in execution, the same state you just had paused is pulled forward.

That is hopefully a straightforward answer as to **why** the system is operating as it does.

As for why 1 is added, Johan's comment on `true` being converted into `1` for the addition is spot on. This is a part of JavaScript's weak typing system.